# Retriving record values from DetailsView in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have the following DetailsView setup:

```
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="QuestionDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="QuestionID,QuizID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Quiz" OnPageIndexChanged="QuestionDetails_PageIndexChanged">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text_Eng" SortExpression="Text_Eng" ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text_Eng") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option1" AccessKey="1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt_1_Eng") %>' GroupName="AnswerOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Option_CheckedChanged" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option2" AccessKey="2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt_2_Eng") %>' GroupName="AnswerOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Option_CheckedChanged"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option3" AccessKey="3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt_3_Eng") %>' GroupName="AnswerOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Option_CheckedChanged"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

Basically, i am displaying a question along with three options from a sqlDataSource which i've verified working.

What i need to do is loop through the records (questions & options) using a button.
then in my code behind, i would like to retrieve values of some of the columns.

This is my code behind:

```
protected void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //try
    //{
        // Save off previous answers
        System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)questionDetails.DataItem;

        // Create Answer object to save values
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionNo"].ToString(); //it breaks here saying "Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        a.CorrectAnswer = dr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
        a.UserAnswer = answerDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

    //}
    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{
    //    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    //}


    if (QuestionDetails.PageIndex == QuestionDetails.PageCount - 1)
    {
        NextButton.Enabled = false;
        //go to evaluate answer page
        //Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        QuestionDetails.PageIndex += 1;
        NextButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (QuestionDetails.PageIndex == QuestionDetails.PageCount - 1)
    {
        NextButton.Text = "Finish the Quiz";
    }

}


protected void Option_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NextButton.Enabled == false)
    {
        NextButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    selectedOptionRB = (RadioButton)sender;
}
```

Here's the line i am having an issue with: a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionNo"].ToString(); //it breaks here saying "Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend storing the Data separately from the View and then disabling View State on the View Control itself and always rebinding. In any case, one of two things are happening - *use the Debugger to find out which!* Either `questionDetails.DataItem` evaluates to null or `dr["QuestionNo"]` evaluates to null. If the click happens in a postback *without* a rebind, I suspect that `DataItem` may itself be null; also, remember that unless a column is *used* as a column in the view, it is not persisted across postbacks. *Using the debugger will quickly isolate which case is occurring.*

Comment: @user2246674 Thanks for the recommendation. Could you point me to an example if that's not much to ask.

Comment: @user2246674 one more thing to note about my sqldatasource, i am querying 3 random records out of a bank of 50 or whatever. So if i do rebind, it's going to get me another random selection (which is not what i want for my scenario)

Comment: For rebinding to a temporal DataSource I find [GenericDataSource](http://genericdatasource.codeplex.com) useful. It can back all the data by ViewState itself (or it might only store the record IDs and proxy to the SQL source/DAL).

Comment: @user2246674 i really couldn't get it. OK I'll rephrase my question: I have a details view with 3 pages (i.e. 3 records). Is it possible to iterate through the rows (retrieve the values of each row; the columns basically) without rebinding? Because if i rebind, i would get a different random selection of rows (which i don't want) ... so sorry but i am sure i haven't explained my self clearer earlier. and if there's a live example that would really help since i am a beginner. much appreciated!

Comment: You rebind to the GDS, not the SDS. Or to the SDS (or store the keys to persist the Keys to fetch the same records). In any case, I gave the instructions in my first comment to track down the NPE!

Comment: @user2246674 would it be too much to ask to write some code? i am truly half way lost! (not totally)

Comment: First, find out which case the NPE is occurring from. No DataItem or no Column in DataItem. (All my last work has been with DevExpress which has it's own .. quirks.)